# Making a shechayanu on clothing

Tags: blessing, clothing

When one buys a new article of clothing that a shechayanu would technically be made on, at what point is the bracha made? When the person purchases it? Or when they wear it for the first time?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/the-blessing-of-shehechiyanu

Answer (score 1):

Rishonim (see Sh.O. O.H. 223:3-4) rule that the brocha should be done when the person purchases the clothes, but achronim (Ben Ish Hai,Rav Ovadya Yosef [in his Shiurim he said this]) say one should recite the brocha only when he actually wears it.

[Here](http://www.halachayomit.co.il/DisplayRead.asp?readID=1453) is an article exactly about this question.

Comment: sources? ......

Comment: Why would all rabbis suddenly change their minds

Comment: @Yehoshua There are sources in the article I've linked, I'll add them to the answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe because now we buy things more frequently and we are really happy only when we start use them.

Comment: @jutky And that socio-economic transition happened coincidentally at the same time as the religo-historical switch from Rishonim to Achronim?

Comment: @DoubleAA do you say it for each machlokes between rishonim and ahronim?

Comment: Do I ask why and when it changed? Absolutely.

Comment: @DoubleAA no, do you ask about coincidence? My previous comment tries to explain the "why" and in the answer you have "when".

Comment: If it's all rishonim vs all achronim, then yes I ask if that is a switch based on external historical reasons or not. Not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not aware of any historical reasons. Anyway, that's not something the questioner was interested in.