# For those who say the b'racha before lighting Yom Tov candles, when do they say shehechiyanu?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, candle-lighting, shehecheyanu

I was taught to say the b'racha on lighting yom-tov candles after lighting, just like for Shabbat, but I understand that [some say the b'racha first on yom tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20243/472).  For those who do and say shehechiyanu at candle lighting, is the sequence: b'racha, light, shehechiyanu, or b'racha, shehechiyanu, light?

An argument for the first would be that we don't make an interruption between a mitzvah and its b'racha.  An argument for the latter would be that we want to tie the b'racha that ushers in the day to the one that gives thanks for reaching it, so maybe there shouldn't be an interruption there.

Comment: We do not drink the Kiddush wine before the Shechiyanu? Why would candles be different?

Comment: @gershon because shehechiyanu has something to do with kiddush

Comment: @gershongold http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11516

Answer (score 2):

R [Moshe Shternbuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moishe_Sternbuch) ([Moadim uZmannim 7:117](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19962&st=&pgnum=198)) says that while the best thing is to say Shehechiyanu at Kiddush like everyone else, a woman who on Yom Tov will say Shehechiyanu at candle lighting and says the blessing on lighting before lighting the candles should be instructed to say the Shechiyanu blessing after lighting the candles to avoid any concerns of interruption between the blessing on lighting and the lighting itself.

Comment: I note if you said Shehechiyanu before lighting, you can for sure no longer extinguish the match you used to light the candle, and you'd have to set it down and let it go out by itself.

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2011/03/28/shehecheyanu-after-lighting-candles/

Answer (score 1):

They say it after the bracha of lights before lighting.

see Hagaos Rabbi Akiva Eiger 263:5 who says it has no real source but don't protest women who do it and he quotes the Yaavetz 107 who discusses this. Chacham Ovadia holds that the shehecheyanu is a hefsek and shouldn't be done by lighting.

Comment: Do you have any source for your initial sentence (the only one that answers the question)?

Comment: If you researched the inyun you will see that there is no mekor rather the Yaavetz justifies it somewhat and the poskim say you don't have to protest,it seems this has become the minhag as I have seen almost all women do this and the Mishna Brurah seif 23 also mentions not to protest,it seems it became very popular

Comment: Also this is how the siddirim(not Gra,or Sephardic )printed it,that could also be a cause of the minhah