# Earliest reference to women making the bracha of Shechayanu by candle lighting on yom tov

Tags: sources-mekorot, yom-tov, provenance, candle-lighting, shehecheyanu

There is a minhag that I think is prevalent in most of klal yisrael that when a woman lights candles in honor of yom tov she at that point recites the bracha of shechayanu (rather than being "yotzee" with the bracha that her husband will make by kiddush.)

When did this Minhag begin as it doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in traditional poskim (Shulchan Aruch, nosei kelim, etc.) The Yavetz in [Siman 107](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43089&st=&pgnum=220) already points out that this is mentioned in the sefer "Kitzur HaShelah" which is says is not a sefer to be relied upon. He doesn't seem to like the minhag however ends off that it's not a bracha l'vatelah and seemingly not so "bad".

In any case, what is the earliest source for the minhag? Is there anything "earlier" than what the Yavetz writes and brings from the sefer Kitzur HaShelah. How did the minhag come about?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11516

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49438&st=&pgnum=48&hilite= http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14580&st=&pgnum=11&hilite= http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22619&st=&pgnum=44&hilite=

Comment: The idea is perhaps obvious (without erudition I try to get a source)
Gemara Brachot 37B דתניא היה עומד ומקריב מנחות בירושלים אומר ברוך שהחיינו וקימנו 

והגיענו לזמן הזה

Tosfoth:וכ''ד משמרות היו וכל שבת מתחדשת משמרה אחרת אם כן כל משמרה אינה משמרת אלא ב' פעמים בשנה וכיון שיש להם זמן קבוע מברכינן שהחיינו ולא כפירש''י דמנחות דמיירי בכהן שלא הקריב מעולם
Many time between 2 YT + zman Kavua. I hope to make a response.

Comment: @kouty That can't be the explanation because how would that explain Shmini Atzeret? The Shehechiyanu is clearly about the day, not the Mitzva of lighting YT candles.

Comment: @DoubleAA+1 for you, But imagine that only YT is a new kind of Menachoth, So Shmini Atsereth comes X 1 yearly. But your Kushia is better than the Teruts.

Comment: @kouty Even with that, why can't you not accept YT and still say Shehechiyanu at candle lighting? Must be it's not a Beracha on the Mitzva of lighting which happens before YT starts.

Comment: @DoubleAA   Of course, The Shehecheyanu is not for the candles but for the days. If one says Shehe. in Kidush before Hadlaka, the women do not say it a second time. This day is initiated with the Hadlaka and so in the Hadlaka we say Shehe. for the whole YT.